# How do I turn the content of a var in an absolute path?

Tags: batch-file

Suppose I have this:

```
set X = ..
```

How do I turn that later into an absolute path? Can you please write how it would be in a script?

I tried with `%~dpX` , but that gave this error message:
`The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~dpX`

Comment: Please, never ever put spaces around the `=` in a `set` statement in batch.

Comment: Can you please give a reason why not?

Comment: Because the spaces become part of the variable name

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching, I figured out a way of doing this:

```
for %%y in (%X%) do set X=%%~dpy
```